# JSON data remains from previous AJAX call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am doing a little app that takes values from different JSON and draw a chart in google chart. I have 8 selectors in groups of 2: 4 for choosing the JSON file of the 4 variables I want to plot (first level) and another 4, as nested, to choose different data of the selected JSON (second level). The first level calls the JSON file, and show the properties as options to choose in a second level selector (as cascading dropdownlist).

When I select form first level and I call my json, the jsonData is correct, but if I change my mind and I want to choose another option from first level, my function return me again the old values.. It only happens since the *secondChoose(jsonData)* function is triggered.

Has anybody any idea why?

Thank you in advance!!

I let you the code below:

```
    var url;
    var id;
    var dataContainer = [];
    var findSelector;
    var keySelected;
    var newDatas;

        $(".firstLevel").on('change', function(){
          url = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("name");
          id = $(this).attr("name");
          $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          crossDomain: true,
          jsonpCallback: 'foo',
          success: secondChoose
          })
        });
        function secondChoose(jsonData) {
          findSelector = $("#"+id);
          findSelector.empty();
          findSelector.append("<option selected>..</option>")
            for (var key in jsonData) {
              findSelector.append("<option class='form-option'>"+key+"</option>")
            }
          findSelector.on('change',function(){
            keySelected = findSelector.find("option:selected").text();
            newDatas = jsonData[keySelected].datas;
            dataContainer.push(newDatas);
          })
        };
```

Comment: Don't declare your function inside the `each()`. It has a severe performance impact. Same goes for the `findSelector.on()`, it should be outside the function so it's not rebound eveytime you call `secondChoose`. Your problem probably comes from there.

Comment: Move `findSelector.on()` out of `secondChoose()` too and tell me if the problem persists.
Also check your browser's debugger to see if the request's response matches what's on the view. If not, the server is probably faulty, else it's your script.

Comment: Thank you!! How can I then execute the findSelector.on() with my json Data if it is outside of the secondChoose function?

Comment: Store your jsonData inside a global variable, declared next to your `url` variable.

Comment: The value of `findSelector` within your on change function may not be what you expect.  That’s easily fixed by using `this`, like `keySelected = $(this).find(...`

Comment: Thank you both! I fixed it creating the global variable with my JSON data.